# The output is having unwanted carriage returns and line feeds.How to remove the carriage returns"\r",in below program?

Tags: c, carriage-return, linefeed

[the below program is for reverse the string till underscore. I am getting the output but with an unwanted carriage return and linefeed. I was trying to remove those "\r" from the program using "!=" but I am confused about where to place. I am the starter in c programming, I searched this doubt in google, but I getting confused .please help to execute this code!][1]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[100];
    fgets(arr,100,stdin);
    int i,j,k=0,l,g=0;
    l=strlen(arr);
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]=='_')
        {
            k=i;
            g=1;
        }
    }
    if(g==1)
    {
        for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            printf("%c",arr[i]);
        }
        for(i=k;i<l;i++)
        {
            printf("%c",arr[i]);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            printf("%c",arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fgets` includes the newline in the string. Also, please [edit] your question and add the code directly into the question as text. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: You should not be receiving a carriage return (`'\r'`) from a text-mode stream.  If you're using a system that uses CR-LF for newlines (i.e., Windows), it should be translated automatically to just `'\n'` for text-mode streams.  The only possibilities I can think of is that you are running your program on a POSIX system and are piping in a text file created on Windows or whatever C implementation you're using is broken.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 char arr[100];
 scanf("%[^\n]%*c,arr);
 int i,j,k=0,l,g=0;
 l=strlen(arr);
 for(i=0;i<l;i++)
 {
  if(arr[i]=='_'){
     k=i;
     g=1;
   }
 }
 if(g==1){
     for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--){
         printf("%c",arr[i]);
     }
     for(i=k;i<l;i++){
         printf("%c",arr[i]);
     }

 }
 else{
     for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--){
         printf("%c",arr[i]);
     }
 }

 }
```

Comment: Instead of posting the whole program, post the parts that you needed to change to fix the issue and give a short explanation of what the change did.

Comment: Code without explanation is not an answer.